# Byte and Signed Short Integer in PHP

Tags: php, integer, byte

I want to send a udp packet in php. I am using mac os x 10.6.

My problem is that I want to send current time separately in hours and minutes, taking one byte each but I could not find the way how to send a byte in php, since byte is not a primitive data type in php. I am also getting problem in sending a signed short integer.

thanks in advance.

Comment: `$hour = pack('C', $hour)`. char is the equivalent of byte.

Comment: and what for short signed int?

Comment: read the pack docs. php makes no distinction between signed/unsigned values for packing. signedness only enters when you're `unpack()`ing.

Comment: I've used $temperature = pack('S', $temperature); but it is not working.